# Easy Share Intent not Showing up except its title

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm following udacity tutorial for sunshine app by google. Here I'm following a code to show easy share intent.But its not working in my phone. [Here is the Link](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/3.13_add_share_action_provider/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/DetailActivity.java) with below code.

item in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="@string/action_share"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionProviderClass="android:support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
 </menu>
```

Activity fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu method

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragment, menu);

         ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider =
                (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

        if (mShareActionProvider != null ) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share Action Provider is null?");
        }
    }

    private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                mForecastStr + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
        return shareIntent;
    }
```

But I'm not getting the share button. This is my Output.

[image]

I'm only getting share button title. Any help please?

Comment: Does "Share Action Provider is null?" appear in your logs?

Comment: @Matt No logs . There are no logs